# How to make fade in/out only happen once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with my product images. I have 2 images stacked and when hovering it fades out the top one and shows the bottom. This works good, but I discovered a small issue. If you repeatedly move your mouse over like 20 times, the animation will continue to happen, until all cycles are complete. How do I stop it to only do it once?

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.product a.product-image .primary-img').hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(300, 0);
  }, function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(300, 1);
  });
});
```

```css
.product a.product-image {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}
.product a.product-image .primary-img {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
}
.product a.product-image .secondary-img {
 position: absolute;
    left: 0;
 top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <a class="product-image" href="#">
    <img class="primary-img" src="http://d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/148828/ma/r8-xsWDWKCM.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="secondary-img" src="http://d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/148821/ma/f2xjw32B2U4.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.product a.product-image .primary-img').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(300,0);
  }, function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(300,1);
  });
});
```

The `true` is a flag used to clear the queue.

`.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )`

https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: That did it! Haven't seen that before, learned something new. Thank you

Comment: To check queue , just put one callback function in fade and check this in console.  $(this).fadeTo(300, 0,function(){console.log(x)});

Answer (score 4):

Just use CSS to toggle the imgs opacity on hover

```css
.product a.product-image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.product-image:hover .primary-img {
  opacity:0;
}

a.product-image:hover .secondary-img {
  opacity:1;
}

a.product-image .secondary-img {
 position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  opacity:0;
}

.primary-img, .secondary-img{
  transition:opacity 300ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
<a class="product-image" href="#">
<img class="primary-img" src="http://d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/148828/ma/r8-xsWDWKCM.jpg" alt="">
<img class="secondary-img" src="http://d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/148821/ma/f2xjw32B2U4.jpg" alt="">
</a>
</div>
```